# How to create JSON object in JAVA

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

I tried to create JSON object. My code:

```
    Map<String,List<Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>>> GroupsMap = new HashMap<String,List<Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>>>();

    List<IamMonitoringServerType> typ = DBProvider.GetAllServerTypesConfiguration();
    for (IamMonitoringServerType type : typ){
        Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> serversMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>> groupList = new ArrayList<Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>>();

        List<IamMonitoringServer> servers = DBProvider.GetServersByType(type);
        for ( IamMonitoringServer server : servers) {
            Map<String,Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            List<Map<String, Object>> serverList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

            String server_name = server.getServerName();
            int id = server.getId().intValue();
            int newest_data_id = DBProvider.getNewestServerDataId(id);

            parameterMap.put("server_id", id);
            parameterMap.put("newest_data_id", newest_data_id);
            serverList.add(parameterMap);
            serversMap.put(server_name, serverList);            
        }
        groupList.add(serversMap);
        GroupsMap.put(type.getServerTypeName(), groupList);
    }
    System.out.println("GsON OBJECT: "+ new Gson().toJson(GroupsMap));
```

and the result looks:

```
{
"GROUP_NAME_1":
[
    {
        "1_server":
        [
            {
                "server_id":17,
                "newest_data_id":991380
            }
        ],
        "2_server":
        [
            {
                "server_id":16,
                "newest_data_id":991383
            }
        ],
        "3_server":
        [
            {
                "server_id":14,
                "newest_data_id":991389
            }
        ]
    }
]
,"GROUP_NAME_2":
[
    {
        "4_server":
        [
            {
                "server_id":1,
                "newest_data_id":991395
            }
        ],
        "5_server":
        [
            {
                "server_id":13,
                "newest_data_id":991382
            }
        ],
        "6_server":
        [
            {
                "server_id":3,
                "newest_data_id":991390
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I want to change this result to format like this (sample for one of groups):

```
{
"GROUP_NAME":
[
    {
        "server_name": "4_server"
        "serverIp": xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        "param":
        [
            {
                "server_id":1,
                "newest_data_id":991395
            }
        ],
        "server_name": "5_server"
        "serverIp": xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        "param":
        [
            {
                "server_id":13,
                "newest_data_id":991382
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I have modified my code, but at this moment I receive only last one server to each group:

```
Map<String,List<Map<String, Object>>> GroupsMap = new HashMap<String,List<Map<String, Object>>>();
    List<IamMonitoringServerType> typ = DBProvider.GetAllServerTypesConfiguration();

    for (IamMonitoringServerType type : typ){
        Map<String, Object> servers_nameMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<Map<String, Object>> groupList = new ArrayList<>();

        List<IamMonitoringServer> servers = DBProvider.GetServersByType(type);

        for ( IamMonitoringServer server : servers) {
            Map<String,Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            List<Map<String, Object>> serverList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

            String server_name = server.getServerName();
            int id = server.getId().intValue();
            int newest_data_id = DBProvider.getNewestServerDataId(id);

            parameterMap.put("server_id", id);
            parameterMap.put("newest_data_id", newest_data_id);
            serverList.add(parameterMap);

            servers_nameMap.put("server_name", server_name);
            servers_nameMap.put("server_ip", server_name);
            servers_nameMap.put("param", serverList);   
        }
        groupList.add(servers_nameMap);
        GroupsMap.put(type.getServerTypeName(), groupList);
    }
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(GroupsMap));
```

I'm beginner in Java programming and I suppose that the reason is change a List of elements to Object. How I should correct my code to receive expected result?

The second question is, how to parse this JSON object on Servlet side when I want to get only specific data e.g server name, list of parameters or specific parameter value?

Comment: Whatever result you are trying to expect is not as per standard format. You are using same key server name, server ip and param multiple times. So it is unaccessible based on key when you render data as output.

Comment: yes, your json structure is questionable. the array in groupname has one object with the same keys (servername,ip...).instead you should make two objects. add }, { between your servers in group

Comment: `HashMap<String,List<Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>>>` screams for a better data model. Also, it's a good idea to become familiar with [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) - variables like `GroupsMap` should not begin with a capital letter.